# How to get notification when any application get crash in Android

Tags: android, crash, android-anr-dialog

Is there any broadcast register available using which my app get notified whenever any application get crash on Android device.

Actual requirement is like, there will be one service running in background which needs to monitor the device for any application crash and if any application get crashed I want to send that crash details to my server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your crash log and Receiver code

Comment: @Krishna I have not written any code, I want to know if it is possible or not. Because I spend hours to find out the answer but I am not successful. So, I posted the question here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any tool like [crittercism](https://docs.apteligent.com/android/android.html) to track your application crash.

Comment: He wants to monitor other apps, not his own

Comment: That is something completely different, not related to this